# passing variable from button to button matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Good evening People,

I want to know how to pass a variable from a button to another in matlab. Here's my code:

```
    function pushbutton4_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    [filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.*', 'Pick a MATLAB code file','MultiSelect', 'on');
    fullfilename=fullfile(pathname,filename);
    b=importdata(fullfilename);
    set(handles.edit7,'string',fullfilename);


    function pushbutton5_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    mamamoa=load('best_network.mat');
    A=mamaoa(b);
    set(handles.edit1,'string',A);
```

The variable b is the one to be to be known in the function pushbutton5.

Comment: Trying to clarify the question. Corrected grammar

Answer (score 0):

You can save your variable `b` within the `appdata` of your figure.

```
function pushbutton4_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    [filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.*', 'Pick a MATLAB code file','MultiSelect', 'on');
    fullfilename = fullfile(pathname,filename);
    b = importdata(fullfilename);
    set(handles.edit7, 'string', fullfilename);

    %// Store b within the appdata
    setappdata(handles.hfig, 'b', b);
end

function pushbutton5_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    mamamoa = load('best_network.mat');

    %// Retrieve b from the appdata
    b = getappdata(handles.hfig, 'b');      
    A = mamaoa(b);
    set(handles.edit1,'string',A);
end
```

Alternately, you could store the data using `guidata` and the `handles` structure although this is not recommended for very large amounts of data as you will notice a performance hit.

```
function pushbutton4_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    [filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.*', 'Pick a MATLAB code file','MultiSelect', 'on');
    fullfilename = fullfile(pathname,filename);

    %// Store it within handles.b
    handles.b = importdata(fullfilename);

    set(handles.edit7, 'string', fullfilename);

    %// Update the guidata
    guidata(handles.hfig, handles);
end

function pushbutton5_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    mamamoa = load('best_network.mat');
    A = mamaoa(handles.b);
    set(handles.edit1,'string',A);
end
```